# почему возвращаю return true если найден а в результате все равно false? vue.js

Tags: vue.js

```js
data() {
    return {
        relatives: {
            main: null,
            spouse: 30,
            childrens: {
                child1: null,
                child2: null,
                child3: null,
                child4: 15,
                child5: null,
            },
            parents: {
                parent1: 50,
                parent2: null,
                parent3: null,
                parent4: null,
            },
        }
    }
}
methods: {
    exists_person(relatives) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(relatives)) {
            if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
                this.exists_person(value);
            } else {
                if (relatives[key] >= 18) {
                    console.log(relatives[key]);
                    return true; //вот это почему то не возвращает как результат всей функции хотя совпадения соответствуют
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
}

if (this.exists_person(this.relatives)) {
    console.log('true');
} else {
    console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: obj  это что? нигде не обьявлен

Comment: исправил там все ок обьект верный

Comment: если правильный объект передадите везде, то работает

Comment: реагирует если только первого ввести main, а если нет то false может дело в точто это функция рекурсивная?

Answer (score 0):

Если выполнение попадает сюда:

```
if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
     this.exists_person(value);
```

то функция ничего не вернет. Т.е. вернет, но не туда, где ждут.

Замени на

```
    return this.exists_person(value);
```

Comment: таким образом оно выполняет первый обьект и второй уже не выполняется.

выполнится только childrens: {
                        child1: null,
                        child2: null,
                        child3: null,
                        child4: 15,
                        child5: null,
                    },